# Java ZK pass parameter from iframe to ZUL differents Servers

Tags: java, iframe, zk

i have a `ZUL` using the `ZK framework` i have something like this

```
<window>
   <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src='http://anotherserver/zules/otherzul.zul?parameter=24'/>
</window>
```

the `zul` i want to show is on a different server which is using the same philosophy this means is using the `ZK framework` as well. in fact i can see the zul using my current code. but i need to pass a parameter a simple `String` as the show above.

my question how can i retrieve the parameter in the target `ZUL` **otherzul.zul** in the example. any help is hugely appreciate.

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that 2 ways.

In the zul directly :

```
<label value="${arg.parameter}"/>
```

The better solution is to do it in the controller/viewmodel.
With this you have a fallback if the arg isn't provided.
You have to do it in the `doAfterCompose`

For MVC extending the `SelectorComposer` the arg is already defined.

```
private int parameter;

@Override
public void doAfterCompose(Component window) throws Exception {
    super.doAfterCompose(window);
    if (arg.containsKey("parameter")) {
        parameter =  (int) arg.get("parameter"));
    } else {
       //Declare what is is when you don't have the arg
    }    
}
```

For MVVM :

```
String queryParam;

@Init
public void init(@QueryParam("parameter") int parm1){
    queryParam = parm1;

}
```

Comment: hello chillworld i was wondering `arg` parameter is declared?

Comment: extended mine answer to make difference of MVC/MVVM and answers your question.